# How do I bind an ASP.NET FormView to a single record?

Tags: asp.net, data-binding

The whole purpose of the ASP.NET FormView control is to display a single record at a time. So how do I bind it to a single record? It complains that

> Data source is an invalid type.  It must be either an IListSource, IEnumerable, or IDataSource.

I can wrap my object in a list if that's the only solution. In this application, the FormView is inside a user control and I'm retrieving the object in a public method, i.e. I'm not using a data source control. I'm not doing any 2-way data binding here either, I'm only using the FormView in this case to maintain a consistent look.

If I went by the book and bound a FormView to a data source that returned a list of records, would it actually retrieve all the records and just display only the selected record?

Here's what I ended up implementing in a utility class:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> WrapInEnumerable<T>(T item)
{
    return new T[] {item};
}
```

Comment: When I tried to implement this on my Linq2Sql entity it still threw the error when casting it to an array. I tried Sani Huttunen's List<> idea and this worked.

Comment: GOTCHA: If you are manually setting the .DataSource property then dont forget the .DataBind() on the next line! Left me scratching my head for a few minutes when I was faced with no error but no data displayed. Obvious in hindsight, but I normally use ObjectDataSource so it wasnt instictive to me

Comment: I just used this myself with one minor difference. I turned this in to an extension method by changing `T item` to `this T item`. Thank you for the great idea with this.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As the error message says, the DataSource object must implement IListSource, IEnumerable or IDataSource to work.

If you have an object av type A which do not implement one of the mentioned interfaces then you could as you say wrap your object in a list:

**C#**

```
var myDataSource = new List<A> {myObject};
```

**VB.NET**

```
Dim myDataSource As List(Of A)(myObject)
```

Comment: Thanks for confirming. It was a bit of a rant disguised as a question. Not that it makes a big difference with one item, but wrapping it in an array is probably more efficient.

Comment: Agree with the rant.  This is stoopid.  The control is designed to show a single item, you should be able to bind the object directly.